# Grouping XML nodes based on the first element value in each node using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping

I have an xml. I need to add new xml node called SUBMITTER and group each SIMPLEQUERY node based on the first element value, which is the SUMBITTERID.

```
    <EIPData>
        <RESULT>
           <SIMPLEQUERY>
                                <SUBMITTERID>1</SUBMITTERID>
                                <FILENAME>KGP_P_092920_172739_Validated.txt.997</FILENAME>
                                <RECEIVEDDATETIME>20201014 T 11:01:31</RECEIVEDDATETIME>
           </SIMPLEQUERY>
           <SIMPLEQUERY>
                                <SUBMITTERID>1</SUBMITTERID>
                                <FILENAME>KGP_P_092920_172739_Validated.txt.997</FILENAME>
                                <RECEIVEDDATETIME>20201014 T 11:01:31</RECEIVEDDATETIME>
           </SIMPLEQUERY>
           <SIMPLEQUERY>
                                <SUBMITTERID>2</SUBMITTERID>
                                <FILENAME>KGP_P_092920_172739_Validated.txt.997</FILENAME>
                                <RECEIVEDDATETIME>20201014 T 11:01:31</RECEIVEDDATETIME>
           </SIMPLEQUERY>
           <SIMPLEQUERY>
                                <SUBMITTERID>2</SUBMITTERID>
                                <FILENAME>KGP_P_092920_172739_Validated.txt.997</FILENAME>
                                <RECEIVEDDATETIME>20201014 T 11:01:31</RECEIVEDDATETIME>
           </SIMPLEQUERY>
           <SIMPLEQUERY>
                                <SUBMITTERID>3</SUBMITTERID>
                                <FILENAME>KGP_P_092920_172739_Validated.txt.997</FILENAME>
                                <RECEIVEDDATETIME>20201014 T 11:01:31</RECEIVEDDATETIME>
           </SIMPLEQUERY>
        </RESULT>
```

My Output should look like following: (Grouping based on the value of the first element, SUBMITTERID)

```
    <EIPData>
        <RESULT>
            <SUBMITTER>
                <SIMPLEQUERY>
                    <SUBMITTERID>1</SUBMITTERID>
                    <FILENAME>KGP_P_092920_172739_Validated.txt.997</FILENAME>
                    <RECEIVEDDATETIME>20201014 T 11:01:31</RECEIVEDDATETIME>
                </SIMPLEQUERY>
                <SIMPLEQUERY>
                    <SUBMITTERID>1</SUBMITTERID>
                    <FILENAME>KGP_P_092920_172739_Validated.txt.997</FILENAME>
                    <RECEIVEDDATETIME>20201014 T 11:01:31</RECEIVEDDATETIME>
                </SIMPLEQUERY>
            </SUBMITTER>
            <SUBMITTER>             
                <SIMPLEQUERY>
                    <SUBMITTERID>2</SUBMITTERID>
                    <FILENAME>KGP_P_092920_172739_Validated.txt.997</FILENAME>
                    <RECEIVEDDATETIME>20201014 T 11:01:31</RECEIVEDDATETIME>
                </SIMPLEQUERY>
                <SIMPLEQUERY>
                    <SUBMITTERID>2</SUBMITTERID>
                    <FILENAME>KGP_P_092920_172739_Validated.txt.997</FILENAME>
                    <RECEIVEDDATETIME>20201014 T 11:01:31</RECEIVEDDATETIME>
                </SIMPLEQUERY>
            </SUBMITTER>
            <SUBMITTER> 
                <SIMPLEQUERY>
                    <SUBMITTERID>3</SUBMITTERID>
                    <FILENAME>KGP_P_092920_172739_Validated.txt.997</FILENAME>
                    <RECEIVEDDATETIME>20201014 T 11:01:31</RECEIVEDDATETIME>
                </SIMPLEQUERY>
            </SUBMITTER>
        </RESULT>
    </EIPData>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of XSLT can you use? XSLT-1.0 or XSLT-2.0 or above? Please provide your attempt via an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64454609/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:template match="RESULT">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="SUBMITTERID">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aiyndP

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:key name="querykey" match="SIMPLEQUERY" use="SUBMITTERID"/>

<xsl:template match="RESULT">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:for-each select="SIMPLEQUERY[generate-id() = generate-id(key('querykey', SUBMITTERID)[1])]">
             <xsl:copy>
                 <xsl:for-each select="key('querykey', SUBMITTERID)">
                     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
                 </xsl:for-each>
             </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aiyndP/1